# Can't add or delete from a Has many through association model in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations, has-many-through

I have this 3 models:

```
class BikeActionGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bike_action_groups_slas
  has_many :slas,through: :bike_action_groups_slas
end

class BikeActionGroupsSla <  ActiveRecord::Base   
  belongs_to :bike_action_group
  belongs_to :sla
end

class Sla < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bike_action_groups_slas
  has_many :bike_action_groups, through: :bike_action_groups_slas
end
```

Whenever I try to add or delete something to `sla.bike_action_groups` it gives me a NoMethodError on the delete or append. I debugged `sla.bike_action_groups` to see the content of it and it doesn't return an array of bike_action_groups, it returns this instead:

`[#<BikeActionGroup id: 2, name: "Wheels">]`

I can't call any methods like delete on this but if I convert it to array with `to_a` I can, only this won't delete it from the actual `sla.bike_action_groups` but from the converted array

this are the methods I use to add or delete:

```
@sla.bike_action_groups << @bike_action_group    
@sla.bike_action_groups.delete(@bike_action_group)
```

Comment: Can you post the method calls you are using? This is the expected behavior of has_many through but I want to see how you are trying to use it before posting my answer.

Comment: have you tried `<<` on `sla.bike_action_groups` ? probably if rails 3 cant add proper intermediate record, you have to use non through relation...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `:dependent => :destroy` in your `has_many` association

```
class BikeActionGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :bike_action_groups_slas, :dependent => :destroy
     has_many :slas,through: :bike_action_groups_slas
end
class BikeActionGroupsSla <  ActiveRecord::Base   
   belongs_to :bike_action_group
   belongs_to :sla
end

class Sla < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :bike_action_groups_slas, :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :bike_action_groups, through: :bike_action_groups_slas
end
```

for more info, go through this [***Link***](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7630)

Comment: Hmm this didn't really change anything

Answer (score 0):

It's just a collection of ActiveRecord objects, not an instance, so you can't call `#delete` or other instance methods on it.

But for sure you should able to build new object on this collection, like this:
`sla.bike_action_groups.build` or `sla.bike_action_groups.new`

to destroy any of instance in this collection, simple get one first:
`sla.bike_action_groups.first.destroy`

Comment: won't it destroy the model itself instead of removing it from the collection?

Comment: `sla.bike_action_groups.first.destroy` it will destroy the sepcific model, not unlink it.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is just unlink it and not delete the `bike_action_group` itself

Comment: @Kupi Sorry didn't mention that you want just to unlink it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `clear`

as in `collection.clear` - removes every object from the collection.
This does not destroy the objects.
See this [link](http://neyric.com/2007/07/08/how-to-delete-a-many-to-many-association-with-rails/#.WdMokGeCxhE)